# Image is missing in Next Js React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a navbar component that simply just displays a logo. It works just fine in a dev environment and when a build the production version and view it locally too. Once it is uploaded to Netlify tho is when the image goes missing randomly. I do have another image that is being used in the same public folder in css for a bg-image and it works fine.

Below is the component that is the navbar and a link to the site to view the issue.

```js
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Image from 'next/image'

import styles from './navbar.module.css';
import logo from '../../public/logo.jpg';

export default function NavigationBar() {
    return(
        <>
            <Navbar className={styles.navbarContainer}>
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
                    <Image
                        src={logo}
                        className={styles.logo}
                        alt="Rumba 405 logo"
                        width="75"
                        height="75"
                    />
                    </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    )
}
```

I might add that I am using React-Bootstrap too tho I doubt that matters.

Here is the link to the current live site: https://rumba405.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

When I opened your image reference, it resolves to

https://rumba405.netlify.app/_ipx/w_96,q_75/%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Flogo.3aab2839.jpg?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Flogo.3aab2839.jpg&w=96&q=75

Which then complains of this error

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'ipx'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/node_modules/@netlify/ipx/dist/index.js\n- /var/task/.netlify/functions-internal/_ipx/_ipx.js\n- /var/task/_ipx.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","trace":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'ipx'","Require stack:","- /var/task/node_modules/@netlify/ipx/dist/index.js","- /var/task/.netlify/functions-internal/_ipx/_ipx.js","- /var/task/_ipx.js","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:202:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:242:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
```

You can try adding `ipx` as a dependency to your project so it resolves it

Netlify [itself notes](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/12/14/next.js-on-netlify-latest-update-introduces-complete-support-for-isr-now-with-revalidate/#:%7E:text=A%20new%20high%2Dperformance%20image%20server%20for%20next/image%20based%20on%20Nuxt%E2%80%99s%20ipx%20project%20and%20On%2Ddemand%20Builders) that they are trying to optimize images on top of `next/image`

Others are [complaining as well .](https://answers.netlify.com/t/nextjs-images-502-responses/52043/5)